# How can I determine if A 34 meter antenna can be used as PTA?

Tags: antennas, pulsars

What are the general requirements for any antenna, e.g., one with 34 m of dish, to be used as PTA (Pulsar Timing Array) monitoring? What are the main formulae to be used?
How can the TOA (time of arrival) be estimated? Is there any requirement for further observations, for instance, that the pulsars were not too far away? Can  the bandwidth in S or X be used as well and with what class of pulsars (slow or fast)?

Comment: What do you mean by PTA? Pulsar timing array? If so this should be indicated in the body of the question, for those who are not familiar with the acronym.

Comment: You can ask the operators, they will usually be able to tell you quite clearly what the equipment they have can be used for and what it can't do, at least not without an upgrade. See this article for an estimate of a radio amateur experiment: http://www.rtl-sdr.com/detecting-pulsars-rotating-neutron-stars-with-an-rtl-sdr/. They claim that a 6m antenna should do, so clearly the size of the antenna is not the problem.

Comment: I was also thinking about using New Horizons as free fall body and Doppler tracking it to search for GWs!!! I wonder if that is possible...